# Debug and Cannot Open Connection to SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

When debugging in SQL, I get the following exception :-

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'
```

When I then set next statement and run the statement again, it works.  It also works when I'm running the application standalone as a compiled application.  Anyone know why this causes an error only when in debug.

The connection is to a remote database sited off-site, not to the local database.

```
Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=TheDatabase;User ID=MasterUser;Password=AsIfIMGoingToPostThat
```

Your help, appreciated.

This is my function to connect...

```
    Public Sub New(ByVal strConnect As String)
    Try
        dbConnect = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnect)
        dbConnect.Open()
        objParams = New List(Of SqlClient.SqlParameter)
        m_bIsConnected = True
    Catch exc As Exception
        m_bIsConnected = False
    Finally
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to connect first time, it looks like I need to add "Network Library=DBMSSOCN;" to connect in debug.  t.b.h., Have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your local connection doesn't default to named pipes but your compiled version will try (or is allowed to use TCP/IP).  The error shows that it may be expecting named pipes.

Try putting this "np:" in the Data Source in your connection string:

```
Data Source=np:xx.xx.xx.xx;  ...
```

Comment: Thx for the advice but unfortunately, it didn't work.  I get "Win32Exception: The network path was not found", the remote database is on a separate system, not on my local or company network.

Comment: Add Connection Timeout=300 to your connection string. This will wait for 5 minutes to establish a connection